# Piping stdout of Process to another stdout

Tags: process, stdout, rust

I'm trying to start a curl download and then pipe it's stdout to the stdout of my program. Here's what I got (still using old_io):

```
let process = Command::new("curl")
    .arg("-o ").arg(&self.filename).arg(&self.url)
    .spawn().ok().expect("Download failed.");

let output = process.wait_with_output().ok().expect("Download failed.");
```

That works perfectly fine, but the curl download takes quite a long time. So it would be neat to display curl's stdout (=> the progress of the download) while it's still downloading and not just at the end. I tried lot's of things, but can't get this thing working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `wait_with_output`, just read from the pipes that are part of `process`. When you can't read anymore, then you can wait for the process. Here's an example with no error handling:

```
#![feature(old_io)]

use std::old_io::process::Command;
use std::old_io::stdio;

fn main() {
    let mut process = Command::new("bash")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo start-$i; sleep 1; echo stop-$i; done")
        .spawn()
        .ok()
        .expect("Command failed");

    let buf = &mut [0; 256];
    while let Ok(bytes) = process.stdout.as_mut().unwrap().read(buf) {
        stdio::stdout_raw().write_all(&buf[..bytes]).unwrap();
    }

    let _ = process.wait_with_output().ok().expect("Download failed.");
}
```

Comment: Is it idiomatic to place `process.stdout.as_mut().unwrap()` into the while loop, and thus execute it on each iteration ?

Comment: I don't know about *idiomatic*, it was simply the easiest thing to show the general shape of the solution. All of the "error handling" here is simply to `panic!()` whenever something's not right. If you can avoid calling that multiple times, it's probably worth it!